# I have a Issue with Copy-Item in Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

My problem is that powershell always gives me the error msg :"cant overwrite file with itself" and i don't know why

```
$source=$textBox1.text
$dest=$textBox2.Text
$usr=$textBox3.text
```

#######From

```
$fNoBackup =               "\\$source\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Local\NoBackup\*"
$fData =                   "\\$source\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data\*"
$fCustomDestinations =     "\\$source\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*"
$fAutomaticDestinations =  "\\$source\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*"
```

#######To

```
$tNoBackup =               "\\$dest\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Local\NoBackup"
$tData =                   "\\$dest\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data"
$tCustomDestinations =     "\\$dest\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations"
$tAutomaticDestinations =  "\\$dest\c$\Users\$usr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations"
```

#######le copy

```
#############"Touch" the files ;D
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $tNoBackup -Force
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $tData -Force
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $tCustomDestinations -Force
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $tAutomaticDestinations -Force

#############Copy
Copy-Item  $fNoBackup               $tNoBackup  -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item  $fData                   $tData  -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item  $fCustomDestinations     $tCustomDestinations  -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item  $fAutomaticDestinations  $tAutomaticDestinations -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, I would recommend that you print out the contents of your variables to the console. That way, you will understand what the problem is.

I don't know Powershell, but I am seeing something which could be a problem. Obviously, `$` within a string has a special meaning (it seems to denote variables). Therefore, I suspect that you have to quote (escape) the `$` sign if you want it to be literal in the string.

In every of your strings, you have `c$`. That should probably be `` c`$ `` since `` ` `` is the escape character in Powershell. When you have done this, print the strings out to the console again to make sure you have got them right.